# PhysX - simulate() never ends if GPU used

Tags: c++, gpu, physx

Im still working on physics system for simulating fluids. I rewrote my application to use PhysX 3.3.0 and to be more objective and now i have a problem which i cant resolve for like a week or two.

This is my initiation of PhysX Context:

```
void PhysXSPH::initContext(void){
    static LogPxErrorCallback gLogPxErrorCallback;
    static PxDefaultAllocator gDefaultAllocatorCallback;

    mFoundation = PxCreateFoundation(PX_PHYSICS_VERSION, gDefaultAllocatorCallback, gLogPxErrorCallback);
    check(mFoundation, "PxFoundation creating failed!");

    static PxProfileZoneManager *mProfileZoneManager = &PxProfileZoneManager::createProfileZoneManager(mFoundation);
    check(mProfileZoneManager, "PxProfileZoneManager creation failed!");

    bool recordMemoryAllocations = true;
    mPhysics = PxCreateBasePhysics(PX_PHYSICS_VERSION, *mFoundation,
        PxTolerancesScale(), recordMemoryAllocations, mProfileZoneManager );
    check(mPhysics, "PxPhysics creating failed!");

    PxRegisterParticles(*mPhysics);
    if(!PxInitExtensions(*mPhysics)){
        check(NULL, "PxInitExtensions failed!");
    }

    static PxSimulationFilterShader gDefaultFilterShader = PxDefaultSimulationFilterShader;
    PxSceneDesc sceneDesc(mPhysics->getTolerancesScale());

    sceneDesc.gravity = PxVec3(0.0f, -9.81f, 0.0f);

    if(!sceneDesc.cpuDispatcher){
        mCpuDispatcher = PxDefaultCpuDispatcherCreate(4);
        check(mCpuDispatcher, "PxDefaultCpuDispatcherCreate failed!");
        sceneDesc.cpuDispatcher = mCpuDispatcher;
    }
    if(!sceneDesc.filterShader){
        sceneDesc.filterShader = gDefaultFilterShader;
    }

#ifdef PX_WINDOWS

    PxCudaContextManagerDesc cudaContextManagerDesc;
    mCudaContextManager = PxCreateCudaContextManager(*mFoundation, cudaContextManagerDesc, mProfileZoneManager);
    if( mCudaContextManager ){
        if( !mCudaContextManager->contextIsValid() ){
            mCudaContextManager->release();
            mCudaContextManager = NULL;
            CLOG(ERROR, "physX")<<"Invalid CUDA context.";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(!sceneDesc.gpuDispatcher){
            sceneDesc.gpuDispatcher = mCudaContextManager->getGpuDispatcher();
        }
        CLOG(INFO, "physX")<<"CUDA context created.";
    } else {
        CLOG(ERROR, "physX")<<"Creating CUDA context manager failed.";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

#endif

    mScene = mPhysics->createScene(sceneDesc);
    check(mScene, "createScene failed!");

    createScene(mScene);
}
```

and initiation of a physX scene but problem occures even with an empty scene:

```
void PhysXSPH::createScene(PxScene *mScene){
    mScene->setVisualizationParameter(PxVisualizationParameter::eSCALE, 1.0);
    mScene->setVisualizationParameter(PxVisualizationParameter::eCOLLISION_SHAPES, 1.0f);
    createPlanes(mScene);
    createParticles(mScene);
    CLOG(INFO, "physX") << "PhysX scene created.";
}

void PhysXSPH::createPlanes(PxScene *mScene){
    PxMaterial* mMaterial = mPhysics->createMaterial(0.5,0.5,0.5);

    //Create actors 
    //1) Create ground plane
    PxReal d = 0.0f;     
    PxTransform pose = PxTransform(PxVec3(0.0f, 0, 0.0f),PxQuat(PxHalfPi, PxVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));

    PxRigidStatic* plane = mPhysics->createRigidStatic(pose);
    check(plane, "Creating plane failed!");

    //create 4 more planes for aquarium

    PxRigidStatic* plane2 = PxCreatePlane(*mPhysics, PxPlane(PxVec3(-4.0f, 0.0, 0.0), PxVec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)), *mMaterial);

    PxRigidStatic* plane3 = PxCreatePlane(*mPhysics, PxPlane(PxVec3(4.0f, 0.0, 0.0), PxVec3(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)), *mMaterial);

    PxRigidStatic* plane4 = PxCreatePlane(*mPhysics, PxPlane(PxVec3(0.0f, 0.0, -4.0f), PxVec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), *mMaterial);

    PxRigidStatic* plane5 = PxCreatePlane(*mPhysics, PxPlane(PxVec3(0.0f, 0.0, 4.0f), PxVec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)), *mMaterial);

    // create shape
    PxShape* shape = plane->createShape(PxPlaneGeometry(), *mMaterial);
    check(shape, "Creating shape failed!");

    mScene->addActor(*plane);

    PxShape* shape2 = plane2->createShape(PxPlaneGeometry(), *mMaterial);
    check(shape2, "Creating shape failed!");
    mScene->addActor(*plane2);


    PxShape* shape3 = plane3->createShape(PxPlaneGeometry(), *mMaterial);
    check(shape3, "Creating shape failed!");
    mScene->addActor(*plane3);

    PxShape* shape4 = plane4->createShape(PxPlaneGeometry(), *mMaterial);
    check(shape4, "Creating shape failed!");
    mScene->addActor(*plane4);

    PxShape* shape5 = plane5->createShape(PxPlaneGeometry(), *mMaterial);
    check(shape5, "Creating shape failed!");
    mScene->addActor(*plane5);
}

void PhysXSPH::createParticles(PxScene *mScene){
    // set immutable properties.
    bool perParticleRestOffset = false;

    //get data from scene model
    int maxParticles = scene->getMaxParticles();
    int xDim = scene->getXDim();
    int yDim = scene->getYDim();
    int zDim = scene->getZDim();

    // create particle system in PhysX SDK
    particleSystem = mPhysics->createParticleFluid(maxParticles, perParticleRestOffset);
    check(particleSystem, "Creating particle system failed!");

    particleSystem->setRestOffset(particleRadius);
    particleSystem->setRestParticleDistance(particleRadius);
    particleSystem->setParticleBaseFlag(PxParticleBaseFlag::eGPU,true);
    // TODO set fluid parameters


    // add particle system to scene, in case creation was successful
    if (particleSystem)
        mScene->addActor(*particleSystem);

    indexes = new PxU32[maxParticles];
    particle_positions = new PxVec3[maxParticles];

    int index=0;
    for(int x=0; x<xDim ;x++){
        for(int y=0; y<yDim ;y++){
            for(int z=0; z<zDim; z++){
                indexes[index]=(PxU32)index;
                int v=3*index;

                particle_positions[index]=PxVec3((physx::PxReal)(scene->m_vPos[v]), (physx::PxReal)(scene->m_vPos[v+1]), (physx::PxReal)(scene->m_vPos[v+2]));

                //CLOG(INFO, "physX")<<index<<"["<<particle_positions[index].x<<"; "<<particle_positions[index].y<<"; "<<particle_positions[index].z<<"]";
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    PxParticleCreationData particleCreationData;
    particleCreationData.numParticles = maxParticles;
    particleCreationData.indexBuffer = PxStrideIterator<const PxU32>(indexes);
    particleCreationData.positionBuffer = PxStrideIterator<const PxVec3>(particle_positions);

    // create particles in *PxParticleSystem* ps
    bool success = particleSystem->createParticles(particleCreationData);
    if(!success){
        CLOG(ERROR, "physX")<<"Creating particles failed.";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

If code in the #ifdef PX_WINDOWS is commented, everything works fine. Fluid flows like it should. But when I try to use my GPU, application freezes on first fetchResult() invokation (simulate() method never finishes its job). I have no error log, it just freezes. It happens no matter if its DEBUG or RELEASE, and if it is 32 or 64 build.

I have a GeForce 560Ti. I use Physx SDK 3.3.0. I link (eg. on win64 debug build) vs:

> opengl32.lib glew32.lib glfw3.lib PhysX3DEBUG_x64.lib
>   PhysX3CommonDEBUG_x64.lib PxTaskDEBUG.lib PhysX3ExtensionsDEBUG.lib
>   PhysXProfileSDKDEBUG.lib

using:

> nvToolsExt64_1.dll PhysX3XHECKED_x64.dll PhysX3CommonCHECKED_x64.dll
>   PhysX3GpuCHECKED_x64.dll PhysX3GpuDEBUG_x64.dll

I tried to use different versions of .libs and add .dlls wanted by the application, but every set ended up with a freezing on fetchResult().

I have no idea where to look for mistakes. Everything looks fine. I'd be thankful for any help!

Comment: I migrated to PhysX 3.2.5 and it works after few api changes. Possibly a bug in PhysX i guess. oO

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I had the exact same problem when I switched from 3.2.5 to 3.3.0.

I did find a solution. The problem is that you initialize the extensions twice here. You are using `PxCreateBasePhysics` to create your SDK object which does some extra work in the background. Namely it calls `PxInitExtensions` if I'm not mistaken.

The fix is to just change the `PxCreateBasePhysics` function to the standard `PxCreatePhysics` call with the exact same arguments. This one doesn't do any additional setups behind the scene. Just leaving out the `InitExtensions` call might work as well but I have only tried the first idea.

It is an odd thing that this only causes the freeze if GPU is in use, maybe nVidia should look at it.

Comment: Funny, I was pretty sure that PxCreatePhysics initializes all of the extensions and PxCreateBasePhysix lets you choose it for yourself. From SDK Documentation:

`If your application requires a subset of this functionality, it is recommended that you call PxCreateBasePhysics as opposed to PxCreatePhysics and then manually register the compoments you require.`

Comment: Code from 3.3.0:

`PX_INLINE physx::PxPhysics* PxCreatePhysics(...)
{
 physx::PxPhysics* physics = PxCreateBasePhysics(version, foundation, scale, trackOutstandingAllocations, profileZoneManager);
 if(!physics)
  return NULL;

 PxRegisterArticulations(*physics);
 PxRegisterHeightFields(*physics);
 PxRegisterCloth(*physics);
 PxRegisterParticles(*physics);

 return physics;
}`